# How to create a BillPayment through the IPP Service

Tags: quickbooks-online

We use the IPP Services to push/fetch data in QuickBooks Online. We're having issues creating a `BillPayment`. There is no "Add a BillPayment" in the provided exemples (/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3).

We've managed to get all the variables right, excepted the `Line` object. It's a little confusing since there's a `Payment` object.

How do you proceed? Is there an existing working/full exemple of this type of transactions?

We tried the following code (copied the `Payment` exemple code) to add the `Line` object:

```
$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setAmount(10);

$LinkedTxn = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_LinkedTxn();
$LinkedTxn->setTxnId('{-84}'); //Is this the Bill Ref ID?
$LinkedTxn->setTxnType('Bill');

$Line->setLinkedTxn($LinkedTxn);

$BillPaymentObject->addLine($Line);
```

`Payment` object variables:

- docNumber
- txnDate
- vendorRef
- payType (value = CreditCardPayment)
- CreditCardPayment (credit card number?)
- totalAmt

The generated error suggests that an Account should be provided. The documentation has `APAccountRef` and `CCAccountRef`, but we tried applying them and failed. The error doesn't provide the information about wether it's the `Line` object that's in an error state or the `Payment` object.

`6000: [A business validation error has occurred while processing your request, Business Validation Error: Vous devez sélectionner un compte pour cette opération.]` (You must select an account for this operation)

Last request XML:

`<billpayment xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <docnumber>11</docnumber>
    <txndate>2014-06-14</txndate>
    <vendorref>8</vendorref>
    <paytype>CreditCardPayment=10</paytype>
    <creditcardpayment>1111222233334444</creditcardpayment>
    <ccaccountref>15</ccaccountref>
    <totalamt>1.50</totalamt>
    <line xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
        <amount>10</amount>
        <linkedtxn xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
            <txnid>11</txnid>
            <txntype>Bill</txntype>
        </linkedtxn>
    </line>
</billpayment>`

Full PHP code exemple without the AUTH part (behold):

```
$str_service = 'QuickBooks_IPP_Service_'.$_REQUEST['type'];
$str_object = 'QuickBooks_IPP_Object_'.$_REQUEST['type'];

//Création d'un item
$Service = new $str_service();
$Object = new $str_object();

$arr_excluded_key = array('token', 'type', 'arr_item', 'billAddrLine1', 'billAddrLine2', 'billAddrCity', 'billAddrCountrySubDivisionCode', 'billAddrPostalCode', 'primaryPhone', 'fax', 'mobile');
//Boucle pour les set
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
     if(!in_array($key, $arr_excluded_key)){
        $str_method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
        $Object->$str_method($value);
    }
 }

 switch($_REQUEST['type']){
    case 'BillPayment':
        foreach($_REQUEST['arr_item'] as $item){
            $Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
            $Line->setAmount(10); //Static for testing purposes

            // The line has a LinkedTxn node which links to the actual bill
            $LinkedTxn = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_LinkedTxn();
             $LinkedTxn->setTxnId('{-11}'); //Static for testing purposes
            $LinkedTxn->setTxnType('Bill');

            $Line->setLinkedTxn($LinkedTxn);

            $Object->addLine($Line);
        }
        break;
}

//Response
#$Service->add($Context, $realm, $Object);
#echo $Service->lastRequest($Context);exit;
if ($resp = $Service->add($Context, $realm, $Object)){
    print($resp);
}
else{
    print($Service->lastError($Context));
}
```

This is the query sent (it's the real URL, it should work for testing purposes): `http://dev.magikweb.ca/magik-net/quickbooks/save.php?token=aaabbbcccddd1234&type=BillPayment&docNumber=11&txnDate=2014-06-14&vendorRef=8&payType=CreditCardPayment=10&CreditCardPayment=1111222233334444&CCAccountRef=15&totalAmt=1.50&arr_item[0][amount]=0.75&arr_item[0][txnId]=11&arr_item[0][amount]=0.75&arr_item[0][txnId]=11`

Comment: Are you getting an actual error or something, or...? Your code looks correct to me... what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I added details in the question area. It's most likely a missing variable, but I can't seem to find which one and how to provide it to the PHP library.

Comment: Where are you getting those XML node names? They aren't in the correct case, and are thus incorrect. Can you post the XML you're generating by calling print($Service->lastRequest($Context)); immediately after calling ->add($Context, $realm, $BillPaymentObject); so we can see the XML that's getting generated?

Comment: I added the last attempt (with CreditCardPayment as a main variable and CCAccountRef). I guess the creditcardpayment is odd...

Comment: Where are you getting this XML from? This code does not generate XML like that... it should be mixed-case, not all lowercase. Your CreditCardPayment node is definitely incorrect, but since you haven't posted your code for it it's hard to tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If the error suggests you specify an account:

> (You must select an account for this operation)

The first thing I would try is specifying an account. Referring to Intuit's documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/billpayment

You'll see there's an `APAccountRef` node that lets you specify an account for the bill payment as a whole.

All of the `QuickBooks_IPP_Object_*` classes have methods that exactly mirror Intuit's documentation/XML node names.

So if you see an XML node named `APAccountRef` there's going to be corresponding methods:

- `->setAPAccountRef($ref);`
- `->getAPAccountRef();`

Have you tried specifying an `APAccountRef` yet?

Regarding this:

> Payment object variables:
>   * docNumber 
>   * txnDate 
>   * vendorRef
>   ...

I'm unsure where you got those from -- they are incorrect. The correct node names are:

- DocNumber
- TxnDate
- VendorRef
- PayType
- CreditCardPayment (or one of the other payment types)
- TotalAmt

The XML is *case-sensitive*, so make sure you use the correct case or you'll get an error.

Regarding this:

> The documentation has APAccountRef and CCAccountRef, but we tried applying them and failed.

How exactly did you "fail"? What did your code look like? What did the XML look like that was sent to Intuit? Did you get the same error, or a different error?

We really need more specifics to help here.

Regarding this:

> How do you proceed?

The best way to troubleshoot is always to:

1. Post all of your code, so we can test and reproduce the issue
2. Post the XML you're sending to Intuit so that we can see what's going on (you can get this by calling `print($Service->lastRequest($Context));` after calling the `->add(...)` method.

Comment: I apologize for being somewhat vague. My code (ironically) mirrors the PHP library (extra layer), I'll add more code (I'll crop what's useless) so you can see! You'll understand how I tried those variables.